# JAXB Marshaller.Listener doesn't play nice with OutputStream

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I want to use [Marshaller.Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html) to insert XML comments, for example, inside the first element.

This works great when marshalling to an XMLStreamWriter.

However, if I marshall to an outputstream (which I'd prefer to do for various reasons), the comment text is written to the middle of the namespace declarations on the root element!

This happens with both the Sun/Oracle and MOXy (2.5.2) implementations.

In the Sun/Oracle implementation, it happens because Sun/Oracle write content to a variable called octetBuffer, and only copy octetBuffer to outputstream periodically. See [UTF8XmlOutput](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/afa88da958e1cfb953fb4c38f0b4a1cfec608162/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/output/UTF8XmlOutput.java#L351).

In MOXy (2.5.2), it looks like [OutputStreamRecord](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/339316cb45b2999ea0979c06677699b034d812ff/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/src/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/record/OutputStreamRecord.java#L602) is using a byte[] buffer in a similar fashion.

I didn't notice any documentation warning me not to touch my outputstream from my listener, but its clear that doing so is problematic unless those internal buffers can first be flushed.

Any ideas for workarounds?